# Error response from daemon: service endpoint with name

Tags: docker

I'm getting this strange error, when I try to run a docker with a name it gives me this error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: service endpoint with name qc.T8 already exists.
```

However, there is no container with this name.

```
> docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

> sudo docker info

Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.12.3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /ahdee/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 28
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-101-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 64
Total Memory: 480.3 GiB
```

Is there anyway I can flush this out?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

TLDR: restart your docker daemon or restart your docker-machine (if you're using that e.g. on a mac).

Edit: As there are more recent posts below, they answer the question better then mine. The Network adapter is stuck on the daemon. I'm updating mine as its possibly 'on top' of the list and people might not scroll down.

1. Restarting your docker daemon / docker service  / docker-machine is the easiest answer.
2. the better answer (via Shalabh Negi):

```
docker network inspect <network name>
docker network disconnect <network name> <container id/ container name>
```

This is also faster in real time if you can find the network as restarting the docker machine/demon/service in my experience is a slow thing. If you use that, please scroll down and click +1 on their answer.

---

So the problem is probably your network adapter (virtual, docker thing, not real): have a quick peek at this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23302.

To prevent it happening again is a bit tricky. It seems there may be an issue with docker where a container exits with a bad status code (e.g. non-zero) that holds the network open. You can't then start a new container with that endpoint.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that forum.  I entered ```docker network disconnect --force bridge qc.T8``` and it seem to work, yah.

Comment: `-force` did the miracle to me, without having to restart the docker daemon.

Comment: 2022 and this works like charm. Thanks !

Answer (score 48):

Just in case someone else needs this. As @Jmons pointed out it was a weird networking issue.  So I solved this by forcing a removal

```
docker network disconnect --force bridge qc.T8
```

A

Comment: this helped A LOT!!

Comment: As described by @ShalabhNegi answer, this command has the following pattern: `docker network disconnect <network name> <container name>`

Answer (score 35):

```
docker network inspect <network name>
docker network disconnect <network name> <container id/ container name>
```

You can also try doing:

```
docker network prune
docker volume prune
docker system prune
```

these commands will help clearing zombie containers, volume and network. 
When no command works then do

```
sudo service docker restart
```

your problem will be solved

Comment: `sudo service docker restart` worked for me, thanks +1

Answer (score 6):

```
docker network rm <network name>
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Restarting docker solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you, I got a problem when I can not disconnect from a network and restart works fine `sudo service docker restart`

Answer (score 1):

I created a script a while back, I think this should help people working with swarm. Using docker-machine this can help a bit.

https://gist.github.com/lcamilo15/7aaaebe71852444ea8f1da5c4c9c84b7

```
declare -a NODE_NAMES=("node_01", "node_02");
declare -a CONTAINER_NAMES=("container_a", "container_b");
declare -a NETWORK_NAMES=("network_1", "network_2");
for x in "${NODE_NAMES[@]}"; do;
    docker-machine env $x;
    eval $(docker-machine env $x)
    for CONTAINER_NAME in "${CONTAINER_NAMES[@]}"; do;
        for NETWORK_NAME in "${NETWORK_NAMES[@]}"; do;
            echo "Disconnecting $CONTAINER_NAME from $NETWORK_NAME"
            docker network disconnect -f $NETWORK_NAME $CONTAINER_NAME;
        done;
    done;
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try seeing if there's any network with that container name by running:

docker network ls

If there is, copy the network id then go on to remove it by running:

docker network rm network-id

Answer (score 0):

This could be because an abrupt removal of a container may leave the network open for that endpoint (container-name).

Try stopping the container first before removing it.
`docker stop <container-name>`. Then `docker rm <container-name>`.

Then `docker run <same-container-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

i think restart docker deamon will solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Even `reboot` did not help in my case. It turned out that port 80 to be assigned by the `nginx` container automatically was in use, even after reboot.  How come?

```
root@IONOS_2: /root/2_proxy # netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:873             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1378/rsync
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1565/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1463/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1742/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      24139/dockerd
tcp6       0      0 :::873                  :::*                    LISTEN      1378/rsync
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      24139/dockerd
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1565/systemd-resolv
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      1447/vsftpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1742/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      24139/dockerd
```

No idea what `nginx: master` means or where it came from. And indeed `1463` is the `PID`:

```
root@IONOS_2: /root/2_proxy # ps aux | grep "nginx"
root       1463  0.0  0.0  43296   908 ?        Ss   00:53   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
root       1464  0.0  0.0  74280  4568 ?        S    00:53   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      30422  0.0  0.0  12108  1060 pts/0    S+   01:23   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

So I tried this:

```
root@IONOS_2: /root/2_proxy # kill 1463

root@IONOS_2: /root/2_proxy # ps aux | grep "nginx"
root      30783  0.0  0.0  12108   980 pts/0    S+   01:24   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

And the problem was gone.

Comment: okay, so this is something else running on your compuer. Nginx is the web server that lots of things use, and probably starts by default on your machine (e.g. look in init.d or whatever your system uses). I would suggest your problem has nothing to do with the original post, but but is just a seperate service already holding the port open. the Original OC was unable to start the container because the *name* of the container was held open by a previous running container, irrelevant of network ports.

Comment: @Jmons Ok, ok, that's virtually true, but I was led to this page in search for a solution to my problem to which I found the solution myself after not getting any clue elsewhere. I added this for those in my situation to give them an additional hint which I did not find here.

Comment: Then you should create a new question that addresses that and add yours as an answer, but I suspect there would be a duplicate. I'm sorry, but You would not have got the error message in the original question, and your solution of stop/starting other applications would not fix someone with an error message of "service endpoint with name XXX already exists" and therefore your answer is in the wrong place, it is wrong and it is misleading.

Comment: Ok, you are wright and I am wrong. Sorry. What now? Can I delete it to make you happy?